# When to use Tween animation in flutter

Tags: flutter, animation, flutter-animation, tween

I am learning how to do animations in flutter and could not understand one thing that is why do we even use `Tween` for getting values ?

The basic function of `Tween` is to give values in between of the begin and end values like a color or for position but one can also do that with `AnimatedContainer`. `AnimatedContainer` provides a curve property and it also changes values after a `setState`. So why should we even use `Tween`

Answer (score 0):

As you noticed `AnimatedContainer` is used in conjunction with `setState`. `Tween` animation can be use in conjunction with `AnimationController`. So you will receive more flexibility working with animations. For example, you may use one controller for few tween animations.

All `Animated...` widgets are lightweight options for making simple animations.

Comment: I did not understand what you mean. Still what is the need of `Tween`, if you can give a code example i will understand better i guess. Thank you.

Comment: All what I want to say `Tween` animatation is a part of code-based animation (more complex animation) than simple change size from one value to another. Here it is the video which explains some things: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GXIJJkq_H8g.

P.S. Your question is like, why should we use `Container(alignment: Alignment.center)` if we have `Center`? Why should we use `forEach` or `for in`if we have `for (...)`? Because language gives you flexible possibilities which can be used depending on situation.